# How Specify the class name of our columns in Responsive Grid View?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I'm trying to build a responsive Views grid using [views responsive grid](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid) module. But added fields in the view is not visible.

I'm confused in adding grid class.Please anybody guide me to set class name, so that fields can be seen in the grid?I have attached screenshot of my settings below.

[image: settingd_resposive grid view]

Answer (score 0):

For Wrapper do not use `<div>` you need to use a name. Ex: magazine_grid_wrapper

Comment: I updated with class name ,still fields are not displaying.

Comment: I didn't understand explanation given in the module.                                              "How to Use"  section in https://www.drupal.org/project/views_responsive_grid

Comment: umm humm, try this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/node/2390355)